# Help me ! how to create auto update in adobe flex 3 air

Tags: air

I am creating an air application. How to create auto update in adobe Flex 3 air?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the following swc file 'applicationupdater_ui.swc'

Check out this from Adobe on the subject http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/index.html?air/update/ApplicationUpdater.html&air/update/class-list.html

You'll find the swc files in the framework folder (\frameworks\libs\air) so flexbuilder should link this for you automatically. You could also check out this [blog article](http://blog.multimediacollege.be/2008/12/using-the-air-15-updater-framework-in-flex/) which helps with a example.